# Any recommendation of i18n-savvy nice menus?

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n

Which of the nice menu modules at this point are i18n-savvy? I've tried [Superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish) and [OM Maximenu](http://drupal.org/project/om_maximenu) with no success, and I'm wondering if I'm doing things wrong or the menus don't understand current language selection.

I'd be grateful for any feedback from people who run this kind of menu on multilingual sites.

Comment: We tried Megamenu once. But not realy a good programmed module. But with some fixes, it works + / -. Probably better nowadays.